# Filereader AUDIO file to input type file

Tags: javascript, php, html5-audio, filereader

I am working on a feature which should allow users to "Drag and Drop" or "Browse" audio files and upload them to the server. The "Browse" part works fine and I can upload the files to the server using PHP. However, I cannot access files with the "drag and drop" feature.

So, how can I store the file name or file data in the the `<input type="file" name="uploaded-file" id="uploadBTN" hidden />` section using the "drag and drop" functionality. I have attached my PHP, HTML, and JS snippets for the code.

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION;

include("Config.php");
include("functions.php");


$user_data = check_login($pdo);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

  function cleanSpecialCharacters($string)
  {
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9.-]/', "", $string); // Removes special chars.
  }

  //$rand = rand(10, 100);
  $streplaceFileName = cleanSpecialCharacters($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']);
  //$audioFile = $rand . "-" . $streplaceFileName;
  $audioFile = $streplaceFileName;
  $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $storeFolder = 'audio/' . $_SESSION['user_name'];

  if (is_dir($storeFolder)) {
  } else {
    mkdir('audio/' . $_SESSION['user_name']);
  }

  if ((!empty($_FILES)) && !empty($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'])) {
    // if (preg_match('/[.](mp3)|(mp4)$/', $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'])) {
    //$filename = $rand . "-" . $streplaceFileName;
    $filename = $streplaceFileName;
    $tempFile = $_FILES['uploaded-file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $filename;
    $_SESSION['file_name_audio'] = $targetFile;
    $check = move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    if ($check)
    {
      $uploadMSG = "File Uploaded Successfully!";
      header("Location: upload-details.php");
    } 
    //}
  }
}


?>
```

```
<main class="container">
  <div>
    <form action="" class="w-100 pt-5" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <div class="uploadBox">
        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
        <h2 class="text-center">Drag & Drop to Upload File</h2>
        <span class="text-center">OR</span>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" for="uploadBTN">&nbsp;&nbsp;Browse File&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="file" name="uploaded-file" id="uploadBTN" hidden />
      </div>
      <div class="tagsInput mt-3">
        <div class="form-div d-flex row justify-content-between">
          
        </div>
        <div class="form-div row d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
          
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn pink-bg text-white mx-auto w-100 px-4 my-3" value="Upload Podcast">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>
```

```
const uploadBox = document.querySelector(".uploadBox"),
  uploadHeading = document.querySelector(".uploadBox h2"),
  uploadBtn = document.querySelector(".uploadBox label"),
  uploadSpan = document.querySelector(".uploadBox span"),
  uploadIcon = document.querySelector(".uploadBox i"),
  uploadInput = document.querySelector('.uploadBox input[type="file"]');
let file;

const uploadedActions = filename => {
  uploadBox.style.justifyContent = "center";
  uploadHeading.innerHTML = "Uploading!";
  uploadSpan.innerHTML = filename;
  uploadBtn.style.display = "none";
  uploadIcon.style.display = "none";
};

uploadBox.addEventListener("drop", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    let fileType = file.type;
    console.log(fileType.split("/")[0]);

    if (fileType.split("/")[0] === "audio") {
      uploadedActions(file.name);
      uploadInput.files[0] = file;
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function () {
        let fileURL = fileReader.result;
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      alert("This is not an audio file.");
      uploadBox.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
```

Comment: _"should store file in input[type="file"]"_ - that is not really possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop#process_the_drop has instructions on how to handle the drop part.

Comment: so isn't there any work around for that. I have seen this feature on many sites...

Comment: You can not make this behave in a way, that actually reading the list of selected files _from the file input field itself_ also contains those dragged&dropped files. But you can handle the dropped files yourself, and I just referred you to an example of how to do that.